# Why "udisksctl" and "mount -o loop" giving different root permissions after mounting?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, loop-device, udisks

I am trying to mount an iso using `udisksctl` and it appears that the `bash` scripts inside these are having only read permission

```
[root@hostname ~]# udisksctl loop-setup -r -f /root/test.iso
Mapped file /root/test.iso as /dev/loop0.

[root@hostname ~]# udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop0
Mounted /dev/loop0 at /media/20190701_130215.

[root@hostname ~]# ll /media/20190701_130215/ISO-002/
total 29
-r--------. 1 root root 20504 Jun 20 07:53 install_patch.sh`
```

But if I mount using `mount -o loop` the permissions are preserverd.

```
[root@hostname ~]# mount -o loop /root/test.iso /media/
mount: /dev/loop2 is write-protected, mounting read-only

[root@hostname ~]# ll /media/ISO-002/
total 29
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 20504 Jun 20 07:53 install_patch.sh
```

I need to execute this script after using and wish to use `udisksctl` insted of `mount -o loop` due to some company restrictions.

Why it is behaving like this?

Is it possible to hack this behaviour and have execute permission with `udisksctl` command?

The system I am running is in kernel `3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64` and RHEL.

**EDIT**

More Info: The iso mentioned above was created using [UltraISO](https://www.ultraiso.com/) from Windows machine. I tried using `mk_iso` utility from Linux to create iso and everything seems fine.

Comment: Check /proc/self/mountinfo udisk might mount the device using different options. Or they set different option when creating loop device